# 401 unauthorized page displays server info. Is this a security issue?

Tags: security, passwords, joomla

I have password protected my /administrator directory
but when I press cancel the site displays a 401 Unauthorized page

> ```
> Unauthorized 
> This server could not verify that you are authorized 
> to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong 
> credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand 
> how to supply the credentials required.
>             Apache Server at www.my-domain.com Port 80
> ```

My issue is with the Apache Server at www.my-domain.com Port 80
I understand that's not really much to go off of (for haxors), 
is there a need to remove that from the page or is it a non-issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be an issue as arriving at that page likely requires that information. For instance if you go to www.mycompanysite.com/wherever in your browser it assumes you to be on port 80 (http). Further, it's giving the external/public name of your server so no internal information is being given out.

That being said, if you want it is not a challenge to change the 401 message. (see here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3680523.htm)